# How should I integrate CrossFit with Martial Arts training for endurance and strength gains?

Tags: workout, exercise-frequency, crossfit

I have been practicing martial art for a number of years, usually about 3 times a week. Recently I've come to conclusion that my fitness level (which is rather low) impedes my progress and MA training I am doing is not enough to increase my fitness, so I joined a Crossfit gym. So far I like it, but my question is how to combine Crossfit with my martial art training for best results. I have about 4 to 5 days a week that I could exercise (depending on work, family circumstances, etc.), about 1-1.5hr a day, and I would like to do at least 2 days of each MA and CF if possible. What would be the best regimen?

MA training is 1 hour (sometimes 1.5 hr) usually involves some cardio exercise which depends on the practice, partners, etc. could be from pretty easy to quite challenging, but does not require too much strength usually. The CF workouts are usually within 1 hour too and depend on WOD. 
So far I feel I am making some progress fitness-wise, but I am concerned that doing fitness training only 2 times a week may be too little to make good progress. Is it true and if yes, what would you advise?

If it's relevant, I'm 37 y.o. male, not very fit but healthy, somewhat overweight (BMI=27).

Update: the aspects I want to improve is primarily endurance and secondarily strength, i.e. I want to be able to do more pushups, more pullups, etc. I don't want to be a powerlifter or competing athlete, just to improve the fitness level.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the aspects of fitness that are you trying to improve?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann thanks, I've added that to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to experience novice gains almost no matter what you do, so expect that the first six weeks or so will be great. If the CrossFit gym is properly run, you'll get stronger and better at not getting tired.

CrossFit varies greatly from gym to gym ("box" to "box"), but the basic formula is generally constant: basic gymnastics, power- and Olympic lifting, and metabolic conditioning (in the form of running, pull-ups, kettlebells, and all manner of other exercises). All of these involve a degree of strength and "endurance" work, so you'll probably see the improvements you're looking for.

You'll probably do fine just splitting up the workouts: CrossFit/martial arts/CrossFit/martial arts. It won't much matter if you mess up the rhythm until you've been at it several months and your progress starts to level off. At that point, you'll probably want to develop or find some structured strength programming. (Most CrossFit gyms can help you with that.)